# Exim Keep a Copy of Sent Email

Tags: exim

Anyone know a good way keep a copy of outgoing email that passes through an Exim mail/smtp server?  I know incoming mail can be copied and piped to a script, but can outgoing mail also be piped to a script?  Any know if it's possible to keep a log of outgoing mail and its contents before mail is sent to its destination?

Answer (score 3):

All that can be done by routers. For example if you want to archive all messages submitted from the local domain, you can create something like that:

```
archiver:
  driver  = redirect
  senders = <SENDER IS FROM LOCAL DOMAIN>
  domains = <RECIPIENT IS FROM OUTER DOMAIN>
  data    = archive@domain.tld
  pipe_transport  = address_pipe
  unseen
```

`senders` and `domains` conditions should be written to match outgoing messages. Verb `unseen` guarantee that message should be proceeded in the usual way after copying to the archive.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try this and see how it works!

Comment: Keep in mind that `archiver` router should be placed before the router performed normal proceeding or it will be never invoked.

Comment: I have successfully used the above snippet with exim 4.94 on Debian. I put the snippet into `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/101_archiver` and that was it. I'm using the `exim4-daemon-heavy` package and the `update-exim4.conf` way of managing the config. Thanks a lot @Kondybas for the snippet!